# Setting up an init script in Amazon AMI

Tags: amazon-ec2

I want to run some scripts to run at the boot of the instance (server by node, and a redis database).

Since Amazon AMI is based on debian, I thought I could use `update-rc.d` to manage scripts.

Hwoever, when I type `update-rc.d` it says the command is not found.

What is the correct way of adding a service to the init script?

I know about CloudFront, but that is for the case when one wants to start up the instance for the first time and install some basic programs, right? For my case, I just want my instance to run some programs when it starts running from the reboot.

The image that I am using is amzn-ami-2011.09.2.x86_64.ext4.

Comment: Not sure, but you might want to take a look at Cloud-Init https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CloudInit